# Is there a (linux) terminal character picker?

Tags: linux, terminal, unicode

I want something like gucharmap that works in a terminal and lets me search. A manpage with all the unicode character names would suffice, as would an ncurses application.

I couldn't find something in 5 minutes of Google searching, so I'm asking here.

Comment: https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/kittens/unicode-input.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get close to what I want with the following:

```
from unicodedata import name
for i in range(0x10ffff):
  print unichr(i), name(unichr(i))
```

and saving the output, but I was hoping that someone else had already compiled and maintained something.

Comment: Sometimes for something this simple it's better to have your own utility.  The bright side is it will always be up to date whenever you need it and will give you precisely the output you need.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
curl http://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html | grep "Small Letters, Cyrillic"
```

It's imperfect, and a little slow, and the output could be cleaned up a little but it'll get you the character code for what you're looking for.  You could save the page and scrub it with a little bit of sed/awk love to get a file with just names and codes.

Comment: It would also be ideal if it displayed the character. Beggars can't be choosers, I guess.

Comment: @AlexR if you're into programming rather than just bash'ing you could write a simple program that parses each line to get the name, the code, and insert the corresponding character.  This would also help to fill out the gaps on that page for the whole alphabets rather than just the beginning code.

Comment: I could probably even enumerate the entire (allocated) unicode space... Looks up how to do it in Python...

Answer (score 0):

#### Dumping / browsing full unicode table

From [Alex R's answer](https://superuser.com/a/861558/178656),

There is my 'dumpUnicode' python3 version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from unicodedata import name

for i in range(0x10FFFF):

  try:
    var = name(chr(i))

  except:
    var = None

  finally:
    if var:
      print("\\U%06X: '%s' %s" % (i,chr(i),var))
```

Then:

```
./dumpUnicode | wc -
 137714  718462 6000155 -

./dumpUnicode | grep SMIL.*SUNGLAS\\\|FONDUE
\U01F60E: '' SMILING FACE WITH SUNGLASSES
\U01FAD5: '' FONDUE
```

( Today: 2023-05-16, with my current version of unicode libraries installed, I could list 137'714 characters )

**Note:** This answer is strongly linked to some other of my posts on StackOverflow: [How to `echo` Unicode on `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76256737/1765658) and 
[Hires (floating point) progress bar in `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68298090/1765658)